# Check between which floats in a list a given float falls

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a list that looks like this:

```
# Ordered list.
a = [0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.9]
```

I need to iterate through a list of floats that looks like this:

```
# Not ordered list.
b = [0.12, 0.53, 0.30, 0.03, 0.77, 0.62, 0.98, 0.01, 0.42, 0.33, 1.3]
```

check between which elements in list `a` each element in list `b` falls, and return the index of the element in `a` (to the right). For example, for the list `b` above the results would look like:

```
indxs = [1, 4, 2, 0, 6, 5, 7, 0, 3, 2, 7]
```

(notice the index 7 which points to an extra element in `a` associated to `> max(a)`)

I could do this with a rather elaborated `for/if` loop as shown below, but I was wondering if there might be an easier way with some function I might not be aware of (`numpy`/`scipy` functions are welcomed)

MWE:

```
indxs = []
for b_el in b:
    # Check if float is to the right of max(a)
    if b_el > max(a):
        indxs.append(len(a))
    else:
        for a_el in a:
            if b_el < a_el:
                indxs.append(a.index(a_el))
                break
            elif b_el == a_el:
                indxs.append(a.index(a_el) + 1)
                break
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ordinary Python solution is the [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module, which has several functions for [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm):

```
>>> [bisect.bisect(a, x) for x in b]
[1, 4, 2, 0, 6, 5, 7, 0, 3, 2, 7]
```

The NumPy solution is [`numpy.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html), which does much the same:

```
>>> numpy.searchsorted(a, b, side='right')
array([1, 4, 2, 0, 6, 5, 7, 0, 3, 2, 7], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an expression:

```
where(b<=a.max(),argmax((b[:,None] - a) < 0,axis=1),len(a))
```

(if a and b are arrays)